# Where Should Node Modules Be Installed?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I've been struggling for a while trying to get installed node modules loaded via JavaScript. I finally got common.js installed and working. However, when I do the following command, the module can't be found:

```
const tbl = require("tableexport");
```

I'm guessing I have the node_modules folder in an incorrect spot. Where should it be? In my case, the URL to my project is something like:

```
domain.com/main/project
```

Right now, node_modules resides in "project".

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "clientssite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Client's Site",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Floyd Resler",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "common.js": "^1.1.1",
    "tableexport": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

The file structure from the root of the domain folder is:

```
adex
    clientsSite
        node_modules
            adler-32
            async
            blobjs
            bootstrap
            cfb
            codepage
            commander
            common.js
            crc-32
            exit-on-epipe
            file-sverjs
            trac
            jquery
            printj
            ssf
            tableexport
            wrench
            xlsx
        package.json
```

I used npm to install the packages.

Comment: Can you post the complete folder structure? Also maybe the package.json file will be useful for debugging your issue.

Comment: I added my package.json file and folder structure to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be confusing node "modules" with "packages". While packages typically utilize modules, they are not the same.

Packages are installed by a program called `npm`. By default, `npm` puts them into the `node_modules` directory when you install a package. The `node_modules` directory is usually in the same directory as your package.json file. After you install a package, you can reference a module in the package using the package name.

Depending on the module system you are using, you will either use `require` or `import` statements to reference modules in your code.

When you write your own modules, you can put them anywhere, but typically they go in the same directory as your package.json file or in a subdirectory of the directory that contains your package.json file. Once you have created a module, you can reference it from other files (which can also be modules) using the path to that module in your `require` or `import` statements rather than a package name.

You do not put your module code in nodes special `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I installed the packages with npm. I began with npm init and then npm install <package>. So, I think I did all that correctly.